# ExtJs rowediting grid combo filter not work after save/update record

Tags: extjs, combobox, grid, extjs4, roweditor

I have rowediting grid that gird have two combos and two text field.

when type some character on combo box that combo box filter that type word from drop down list
select that filter value and form combo and do save record ok and gird view record correctly 
NEXT---
after that select one of the gird record and start edit that record.type some character on combo box but that combo don't filter that type word form drop down list.

note: that happen `clearFilter(true);` after save/update record. If i remove `clearFilter(true);` gird view combo filtered result only that why I clear filter data before load store

This is my combo box grid column

```
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    itemId: 'colId',
    width: 140,
    dataIndex: 'ID',
    menuDisabled: true,
    text: 'Name',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        id: 'cbold',
        itemId: 'cbold',
        name: 'CBO_ID',
        allowBlank: false,
        displayField: 'NAME',
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: 'Store',
        valueField: 'FIELD_ID'
    }
},
```

This gird RowRditing

```
            plugins: [
                Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                    saveBtnText: 'Save',
                    pluginId: 'grdEditor',
                    autoCancel: false,
                    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
                    listeners: {
                        edit: {
                            fn: me.onRowEditingEdit,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                })
            ],
```

onRowEditingEdit function

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'url',
    method: 'POST',
    scope:this,
    success : function(options, eOpts) {
        var store       = Ext.getStore('GridStore');
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridFileLyt');

        cbo1Store = Ext.getStore('cbo1Store');
        cbo1Store.clearFilter(true);
        cbo1Store.load();

        cbo2Store = Ext.getStore(cbo2Store);
        cbo2Store..clearFilter(true);
        fldStore.proxy.extraParams = {
            '_ID': ''
        };
        cbo2Store.load();

        if(response.success){
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', response.msg);

        } else {

            Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.msg);


        }
    }

});
```

I feel i did some basic mistake please help to me

Comment: Why do you even intervene on your combo box stores in the onRowEditingEdit function? By default, ExtJs handles these stores and their filters automatically.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer  when i don't clear combo store after grid save. grid only view last time filter result only that why I clear filters

Comment: I can't tell you what is different, but I only remove filter on grid. The combos are managed correctly by ExtJs.

Answer (score 1):

Same story here, bro.

I actively use ExtJS 4 and RowEditing since 2011, it always worked, until today when I found this bug. 
I could not even Google it until I debugged and found out a workaround with clearFilter():

```
rowEditingPlugin.on('beforeedit', function(editor, e) {
    editor.editor.form.getFields().each(function(field){
        if (field instanceof Ext.form.field.ComboBox) {
            field.store.clearFilter(true);
        }
    });
});
```